# How to need to annotate ingresses for traefik to generate letsencrypt certificates

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress, traefik-ingress, kubernetes-helm

I am using traefik as an ingress-controller and want to serve other ingresses via auto-generated letsencrypt certificates and enforce SSL.

I set up traefik with it's official helm chart like this:

> helm install stable/traefik --name traefik --set dashboard.enabled=true,dashboard.domain=traefik.mycompany.com,rbac.enabled=true,externalIP=123.456.789.123,ssl.enabled=true,ssl.enforced=true,ssl.permanentRedirect=true,acme.enabled=true,acme.staging=false,acme.challengeType=http-01

How do I need to annotate the ingresses for the apps I need to expose to use an auto-generated letsencrypt certificate?

With this setup traefik.mycompany.com is delivered via SSL with a wild-card certificate of the default host `*.example.com`:

[image]

I digged through the whole traefik documentation (https://docs.traefik.io/) but could only find out how I need to setup the ingresses.

Comment: https://medium.com/@carlosedp/multiple-traefik-ingresses-with-letsencrypt-https-certificates-on-kubernetes-b590550280cf

Comment: This is the piece of documentation you are looking for: https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/acme/#wildcard-domains If you are trying to get wildcard certs generated then it has nothing to do with ingress annotations, you are looking at a wrong place.

Comment: could you send traefik logs? Maybe for some reason traefik can't generate certificates for you.

Comment: That was indeed part of the problem. I solved it myself and will provide a proper answer when I find the time.